# If two datasets have some overlapping identical records, how can I exclude from second dataset? Equivalent to SQL EXCEPT or MINUS

Tags: java, function, data-structures, methods

If I have two datasets as follows:

Dataset 1

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| John | 32 |
| Vic | 29 |
| Mary | 28 |
| Rea | 29 |

Dataset 2 :

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| John | 32 |
| Joe | 37 |
| Mary | 28 |
| Bo | 35 |

I want to have dataset 2 look at dataset 1, and exclude the duplicate records of John and Mary.

So, dataset 2 should only include Joe and Bo.

SQL has EXCEPT, MINUS or NOT EXISTS. Does Java have an equivalent method?

Comment: It all depends on how the data is stored in java, there are methods that do similar things for various formats, but what have you tried so far? If the data sets are not large then you could simply iterate through the second dataset with a simple `for` loop for example and remove any of the ones that exist in the first list.

Comment: I posted an answer despite the lack of detail. If that answer doesn't address what you're looking for, please update your question with additional detail to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can use streams:

```
dataset2.stream().filter(o -> !dataset1.contains(o));
```

In case your data is stored in a list:

```
List<Object> filtered = dataset2.stream()
        .filter(o -> !dataset1.contains(o))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This does nothing as there is no terminal operation.

Comment: OP didn't specify expected datatype, so no terminal operation. Anyway I added example for a list

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options available to you, of course depending on the starting point. Here's a way to solve this if your starting point is [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) containing Strings (name) and Integers (age).

To start, here is the creation of two maps, as well as populating them with data:

```
Map<String, Integer> data1 = new HashMap<>();
data1.put("John", 32);
data1.put("Vic", 29);
data1.put("Mary", 28);
data1.put("Rea", 29);

Map<String, Integer> data2 = new HashMap<>();
data2.put("John", 32);
data2.put("Joe", 37);
data2.put("Mary", 28);
data2.put("Bo", 35);
```

This line gets all of the keys ("John", "Vic", etc.) from one set, and calls [`removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) to remove those keys altogether if they're present in the other set. So "John" and "Mary" are removed from the keys, and because it's a map, when the key goes, the value goes too. So if "John,32" is present in both sets, removing the "John" key will remove the "32" as well.

```
data1.keySet().removeAll(data2.keySet());
```

Here's the same line, but with a println() before and after, and the output from running it:

```
System.out.println("data1.keySet(): " + data1);
data1.keySet().removeAll(data2.keySet());
System.out.println("data1.keySet(): " + data1);

data1.keySet(): {Vic=29, John=32, Mary=28, Rea=29}
data1.keySet(): {Vic=29, Rea=29}
```